# iOS - Auto-Import new images from image gallery

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller

There are many examples to import one or many images from gallery using UIImagePicker, however I want to detect new images automatically (just like dropbox) and import new images inside my app. Is there any way I can detect new images without opening imagepicker? if not what are the possibilities? Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get all images information without UIImagePicker by using [ALAssetLibrary](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) it will gives you all images and video information, you can store it locally in coredata and perodically check it if there is an image/video info from ALAssetLibrary which is not in you coredata hanse it’s a new image/video.

ALAssetLibrary example code from my personal app and it works prefectoly

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop)
 {
     [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop)
      {
          if (alAsset)
          {
              ALAssetRepresentation *representation =[alAsset defaultRepresentation];
              NSURL *url = [representation url];
              NSString *assetType=[alAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];

              // You can store this info in coreData
          }
      }];
 } failureBlock: ^(NSError *error)
 {
     UIAlertView *alrt = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Permission Denied" message:@"Apple restrictions prevent our app from accessing your Library without your permission. In order to access your media you must enable privacy setting " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alrt show];
 }
 ];
```